# NodeJS Basic Auth - Where is it stored in front end?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

So i am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/basic-auth and everything works as it is suppose to but i cannot figure out how for the life of me!

My setup is simple, when you authenticate you are admin, otherwise you are not. What i am trying to do is display a certain navigation bar on the front end based upon if the user is admin of not.

**NodeJS MiddleWare Code:**

```
exports.login = function (req, res, next) {
 console.log(req.header);

 function unauthorized(res) {
   res.set('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm=Authorization Required');
   return res.sendStatus(401);
 };

  var user = basicAuth(req);

  if (!user || !user.name || !user.pass) {
     return unauthorized(res);
  };

   if (user.name === 'Admin' && user.pass === 'myPassword') {

   return next();
   } else {
   return unauthorized(res);
  };
};
```

Ive checked local storage, cookies, everything that i can think of but once logged in the basic auth magically appears in the headers automatically. If i am to login using incorrect credentials an unauthorized object is returned and logged on the front end, but if i authenticate properly there is no object that i can see.

Any help is greatly appreciated. If you require any additional code, etc. please let me know!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, if `(!user || !user.name || !user.pass)` then you `return unauthorized(res);` the `unauthorised` function is defined earlier and that is responsible for sending the status and headers back to the front end.

But in a case of a successful login `(user.name === 'Admin' && user.pass === 'myPassword')`you only have `return next()` the next function moves to the next middleware in your code.

To achieve what you want, you should actually return something to the front end:

```
if (user.name === 'Admin' && user.pass === 'myPassword') { 
 res.end('Access granted');
}
```